# Fabric object leaves drawing trace on HTML5 canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an issue where fabric object leaves drawing trace on HTML5 canvas.

Let me explain the issue with the bottom picture:

Green area is fabric canvas.

Grey area is HTML5 canvas.

The first row shows the brown square (it's a fabric Rectangle) in fabric canvas. When I move it around within the fabric canvas, it's all good. It doesn't leave any drawing trace.

Now the second row shows drawing trace that was left behind after I moved the brown square from fabric canvas to HTML5 canvas.

My question is why is it doing that?

Is there a way to tell fabric objects to only draw within the fabric canvas scope?

Thank you!

Handi
[image]
**UPDATE:** Never mind with my question. I found out that I was setting the width and height in the wrong way. Was using canvas.width instead of canvas.setWidth.

Comment: i do not know how are you moving the fabricobject over a non fabric canvas. But hos is clearing the html5 canvas when you redraw? are you doing it manually?

Comment: Never mind with my question. I found out that I was setting the width and height in the wrong way. Was using canvas.width instead of canvas.setWidth. Thank you AndreaBogazzi.